# Cut everything after dash in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've got the array of string looks like that:

```
Cola-12-0-15-300-122
Pepsi-123-34-543
7_Up-rrr-12-2342-2
Fanta_Mineral-1212-fgdfg-33
```

And I need to retrieve from these values just the first words till the dash.

So I will have

```
Cola
Pepsi
7_up
Fanta_Mineral
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `-replace` operator to remove everything after the first `-` with `-replace '-.*'`

```
$strings = -split @'
Pepsi-123-34-543
7_Up-rrr-12-2342-2
Fanta_Mineral-1212-fgdfg-33
'@

$strings -replace '-.*'
```

Outputs:

```
Cola
Pepsi
7_Up
Fanta_Mineral
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$Strings = @(
    'Cola-12-0-15-300-122',
    'Pepsi-123-34-543',
    '7_Up-rrr-12-2342-2',
    'Fanta_Mineral-1212-fgdfg-33'
)

$FirstWord = $Strings | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -split '-')[0]
}

$FirstWord
```